# How to refresh the shared list in the Finder's side panel?

Tags: network, finder, wifi, sharing

In the left side of the Finder, under `favorites` and `devices` there is a `shared` list that contains computers and other devices on the network. I use the MacBook in two places, both with wifi. When I switch between these places, the Mac automatically connects to the wifi network there, but sometimes the Finder's shared list still contains the devices in the previous network.

If I close the laptop's lid and open it again, the list refreshes, but is there any other/better way to trigger the refresh? Why doesn't the refresh happens automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Relaunch the Finder

<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>right click</kbd> [or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>left click</kbd>] the Finder icon in the Dock, last item is Relaunch.

Or try this I found on StackOverflow [Automator Command to Refresh ALL Finder/all Finder Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788558/automator-command-to-refresh-all-finder-all-finder-windows) - works for Finder windows, can't test for Shared items.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat


end tell
```

Or use **Terminal** app to performing it manually

```
killall Finder
```

Answer (score 4):

Also turning WiFi off and back on should refresh the shared list.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the very same problem (OS X El Capitan) and refreshing the Finder didn't work out for me. Neither turning off and then back on the WiFi.

What worked for me was restarting the router.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote machine is not listed in Finder window, try this:-

Click on the Apple icon (top left) and look through "Recent Items" list, if the share is listed, simply click on the share name and it will automatically re-appear in Finder.

Obviously this will only work if you have not cleared the recent items list!

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly and reconnected the Windows network drive even though the computer no longer appeared in the `Network` tab

Answer (score 0):

One method I've found to refresh the list of shared computers in the sidebar ***without*** quitting the Finder or restarting the machine is this:

```
$ sudo ipconfig set en1 DHCP
```

(replace `en1` with whatever interface is active on your system)

Another, slightly more disruptive command that works for me is to completely down the network interface(s) with `ifconfig` and then bring them back up:

```
$ sudo ifconfig en1 down; sleep 1; sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

This has the unfortunate side-effect of killing any active states/connections (including virtual machine traffic). So, the first command is usually preferred. I am still actively seeking more precise means to refresh whatever daemon is caching this information.